# Login user automatically but keep password protection

Tags: windows-10

Use case: 
I would like to start my computer, leave it, come back and log in, and then everything is ready for me.

By everything is ready, I mean that all programs are running as if I had logged in and then locked my computer. Except I have haven't even logged in yet, and I don't want to remove my password protection.

Can this be done? How?

Comment: I believe modern versions of Windows 10 do this by default. At least if you have only one user, not sure if it works the same way otherwise.

Comment: **I don't believe what you want is possible.**  Most software will not automatically start unless a user is logged in.  Which means you would have to set the default user to automatically log-in.  You can configure your system to automatically lock after a short amount of time.  However, that lockout period, will always apply for any activity.

Comment: @gronostaj, you are right. Will you please add that as an answer, then I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe modern versions of Windows 10 do this by default. At least if you have only one user, not sure if it works the same way otherwise.

I'm using a local account. @Daniel B confirmed in comments that this works for Microsoft accounts too.

<sub>(original comment posted as an answer by OP's request)</sub>

Comment: Same behavior for me. I login using a Microsoft account with a PIN. It does not work that way on my work PC (Active Directory account) though.

Answer (score -1):

Using sleep or hibernate instead of "Shut down" or "Sign out" on last use does that. Then the process in your scenario would be: "*Wake* my computer, leave it, come back and log in and everything is ready for me."

You would just want to adjust the power settings for long enough to cover the "leave it" part of your process so the computer doesn't return to a sleep or hibernate state while away. You are required by default to put in your password anytime the PC sleeps or hibernates and you can always use Win + L keys to lock the PC anytime you walk away.